# How to reuse Angular resource functions?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

I'm writing a relatively simple Angular application that is similar to a Mailbox app - it consists of Inbox and several other "folders". The idea is to have messages (my Angular model being Message) and to have folders show a number of messages in each of them.

This is easy enough to do for Inbox (first page you land on) as I can just get my messages from an Angular resource like so:

```
Messages.get({location: 'inbox'}, function(data){
    $scope.messages = data.objects;
});
```

To show the number of messages in inbox in my view, it's enough to use this bit of code

```
<p>{{messages.length}}</p>
```

However, I'm having trouble finding a good way to get the number of messages in other folders without repeating myself. I'd like to get this information as efficiently as possible and to make the code reusable as well. For instance, to get the number of messages in outbox (without getting all outbox messages at once, just the number) I could write:

```
Messages.get({location: 'outbox', meta_only : true}, function(data){
    $scope.outbox_number = data.meta.total_count;
});
```

This is not good enough as I still had to write $scope.outbox_number right in that code and cannot make it into a generic function that would take in any folder name as a parameter.

My question is - how do I reuse a function that relies on $resource to get the data I want?  Also, would it be best to have a separate controller for my folders and for my messages pane?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    Messages.get({location: $scope.location, meta_only:true},function(data) {

        $scope.number[$scope.location] = data.meta.total_count;

    }, function(error) {

    });
```

so now youll have in $scope.number.outbox for example, you can change the $scope.location to what you want in each controller and you'll get $scope.number.[location you specified];